# In python, how to increase the current y-axis size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In python, how to increase the current y-axis size?
Assuming, in the normal plot it is [0,50000]and [0,20000], but I want it to be [0,50000] and [0,50000]... [0,50000]. All histograms with y axis from 0 to 50000.

```
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 3, figsize = (18, 18))
sns.distplot(df["EXT"], bins = 40, kde = False, 
             ax = axs[0, 0], color = sns.color_palette()[0]).set_title("Extroversion")
sns.distplot(df["EST"], bins = 40, kde = False, 
             ax = axs[0, 1], color = sns.color_palette()[1]).set_title("Neuroticism")
sns.distplot(df["AGR"], bins = 40, kde = False, 
             ax = axs[1, 0], color = sns.color_palette()[2]).set_title("Agreeableness")
sns.distplot(df["CSN"], bins = 40, kde = False, 
             ax = axs[1, 1], color = sns.color_palette()[3]).set_title("Conscientiousness")
sns.distplot(df["OPN"], bins = 40, kde = False, 
             ax = axs[2, 0], color = sns.color_palette()[4]).set_title("Openness")

fig.delaxes(axs[2, 1])
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel = None, ylabel = "Count")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like what you want to achieve is to use the same axis limits in both subplots, which is most easily achieved by adding `sharey=True` in `plt.subplots`.

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

or

```
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

in your case probably `axs` instead of `ax`

---------------edit--------------

I can't try your code starting from `sns.distplot...`

I tried the code below, however with minor change at how I created the figure itself. btw either `9,9` or `18,18` won't make any difference, it's just that my screen is not big enough to see all if I use `18,18`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
axs = []
for i in range(1,7):
    axs.append(fig.add_subplot(3,2,i))
    axs[i-1].set_ylim([0,1000])
```

With the code above, you will just see this:
[image]
I guess that should solve the main problem of your question, if I understand it correctly?

Comment: I had already used both, and nothing.
But which line would it be to put?

Comment: I edited my answer. The code in my edit should be on the first line, replacing ``fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 3, figsize = (18, 18))``. But your code below would have to be edited accordingly for it to work (I think), I can't help regarding changing the code below as I have no idea about ``sns.distplot``

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel = None, ylabel = "Count"),
    ax.set_ylim(0, 50000)
```